# Application force close, when trying to set one TextView on customListAdapter

Tags: android, textview, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

I want to set text in TexView, actually i store number in array list but,it always force close. so, i try just set manually though, it still force close. I have no idea why others textview able to set but, `amountStr` cannot be set.

Thanks you in advance for your suggestion.

Here some code:

**ActActivity.class**

```
public class ActActivity extends ListActivity {

    private CustomListAdapter listAdapter;
    private String[] activities_list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        activities_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Activities_array);

        listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item_choose_activities,activities_list);      

        setListAdapter(listAdapter);

    } 

    private class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        private String[] items;
        public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items );
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if(v == null){
                LayoutInflater  vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_choose_activities, null);
            }

            TextView actNameStr = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_act_txt);
            ImageView actLogo = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.act_logo);
            TextView amountStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.amount_text);

            actNameStr.setText(items[position]);
            // i wanna set text number here, actually i store number in array list but,it always force close. so, i try just set manually though, it still force close.
            amountStr.setText("5");


            //Set icon of activity on each list items
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                actLogo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a01_ofroad);
                break;
            case 1:
                actLogo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a02_bungeejump);
                break;
            case 2:
                actLogo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a03_art);
                break;
                        default:
                actLogo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nologo);
                break;
            }   
        return v;
    }

  }
}
```

**list_item_choose_activities.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/act_logo" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
    android:background="@drawable/nologo"
    />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/list_act_txt" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/act_logo"
    android:textColor="#494644"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:textStyle="bold"
   >    
</TextView>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/list_bubble"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/list_bubble_num">
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/amount_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="0"
    />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at com.april.travel.ActActivity$CustomListAdapter.getView(ActActivity.java:181)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-09 16:38:47.051: E/AndroidRuntime(21240):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextView amountStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.amount_text);` maybe you need change to:
`TextView amountStr = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.amount_text);`

Comment: LOL. what an stupid i am? My brain+Eye need some rest.  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing an reference to **v** in

TextView amountStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.amount_text);

?

Shouldn't it be

TextView amountStr = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.amount_text);

?